# Mysql fetch last element of group

Tags: mysql, grouping, getlatest

Good morning,

I am trying to get the most up to date element of a group from the database but no luck so far. Ideas anyone? I guess the solution is quite easy but I am really stuck there...

**Data:**

```
+---------------+----------+-------+------------+---------------------+
| transition_id | field_id | value | changed_by | changed             |
+---------------+----------+-------+------------+---------------------+
| 3             | 1        | Data  | Mike       | 2018-08-13 00:00:00 |
| 3             | 2        | Data  | Mike       | 2018-08-13 00:00:00 |
| 3             | 3        | Data  | Mike       | 2018-08-13 00:00:00 |
| 3             | 1        | Data  | Mike       | 2018-08-20 00:00:00 |
| 4             | 1        | Data  | Mike       | 2018-08-15 00:00:00 |
+---------------+----------+-------+------------+---------------------+
```

**Expected results:**

```
+---------------+----------+-------+------------+---------------------+
| transition_id | field_id | value | changed_by | changed             |
+---------------+----------+-------+------------+---------------------+
| 3             | 2        | Data  | Mike       | 2018-08-13 00:00:00 |
| 3             | 3        | Data  | Mike       | 2018-08-13 00:00:00 |
| 3             | 1        | Data  | Mike       | 2018-08-20 00:00:00 |
| 4             | 1        | Data  | Mike       | 2018-08-15 00:00:00 |
+---------------+----------+-------+------------+---------------------+
```

*Grouping:* 
transition_id, field_id

I tried using a left join on the table itself, but this is only returning a single item.

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM table t1 
LEFT JOIN table t2 ON (t1.event = t2.event AND t1.update < t2.update) 
WHERE t2.update IS NULL AND t1.event = 81
```

Thank you for your help!
André

**Fiddle:** 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b24ddb/4

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Thank you Strawberry, helpful hint!

Comment: BTW, I don't understand why you would expect more than one row to be returned!

Comment: My apologies, you are right. I have corrected the data. 
The table represents a log file - every time VALUE is updated it created a new entry for the same TRANSITION_ID & FIELD_ID. I want to fetch the latest status per TRANSITION_ID and FIELD_ID.

Comment: Well, you have a solution now, courtesy of fa06

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
select x.* from tablename x
inner join 
(select event, item, max(update) as mupdate from tablename
group by event, item)a
on x.event=a.event and x.item=a.item and x.update=a.mupdate
```

Comment: Hi fa06, thank you for the fast response! 
I could not get it to work though...

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b24ddb/4

Comment: it was a typo mistake @Strawberry it will be x.item=a.item but by mistake I put x.item=x.item

Comment: Thank you very much @fa06 !